Group message problem
When I send a group text to this one group there is one (very difficult) person claiming she does not get it. But as the group text proceeds and she is personally asked to respond, she will respond.
Can a person be in a group text on the same thread and not see part of the thread?

Welcome to Ask Different. The short answer is it depends. Is this group exclusively Messages recipients or is it sent via SMS (blue or green bubble on iOS 17 and lower)?

If you are a member of a group conversation, you'll see all messages sent to that group. What could happen is that, due to Screen Time or app settings, someone doesn't get a notification when a message arrives, maybe is that the issue? You mention this is about a "very difficult person"... has she shown your or sent you a screenshot of her iPhone or Mac with the "gaps" in the conversation?

it seems possible that she has some setting enabled that hides your messages. There are a couple of non-tech-saavy members in my family that accidentally misconfigured something in their account, and now when theres a group chat, i am prohibited from replying. A different problem, but it illustrates that it could be a technical glitch unique to you & her.
